# Jquery Validation MVC3 asp.net not showing Validation msg

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

I have this on my model

```
    [Required]
    public string AppName { get; set; }
```

on my layout page i have

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>



my view has this inside BeginForm


   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.App.AppName, new { size = 35 })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.App.AppName)
    <input type="submit" value="Start Business" class="demo-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all" />


this is how its rendered

            <input id="App_AppName" class="text-box single-line watermark" type="text" value="" name="App.AppName" data-val-required="The AppName field is required." data-val="true">

<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="App.AppName"></span>
```

when i hit submit i do not get any validation saying AppName is Required but it just post-backs to server with empty field.

i added few field as hidden with validationMsgFor and that is working.

so what i have is

```
public class AppContent
{

    public App App { get; set; }                
    public bool CreateModal { get; set; }
    public AppContent()
    {

    }

}
```

and my view is of type AppContent.

one thing i noticed was when i just add a view with App object directly AppName is detected as required. but when i do it using AppCOntent which has type AppName the validation is not shown, but for other hidden fields that are non-string it works.

Comment: @JustinHolmes, try to use a TextboxFor instead. does it make a difference?

Comment: You have missed out `jquery.js` file. You need three files for unobtrusive validation to work `jQuery (~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js), jQuery Validate (~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js) and the MVC plugin for unobtrusive client validation with jQuery Validate (~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js)`

Comment: i do have jquery.js refrence, validation works for hidden textbox not for this text box that is visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was because of the watermark i had, i had to use place holder instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable client validation in your web.config.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: i have that in my web.config

Answer (score 0):

You have to put this script

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```